# Do we really need Performance in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was browsing through some Documentation tags, when I stumbled upon the [performance documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/performance). There have been absolutely **zero changes** ever since it was created (over a month ago). Should it be removed? Or more generally, should any topics in Documentation with no actual information be removed after some time?

Comment: zero documentation at least indicates to users that it is recognized as a topic, but no one has volunteered the effort. I like place holders, but I understand not everyone does ;-). Will be interested to see what happens with this Q. Good luck to all.

Comment: In my opinion, empty documentations show that people gave up trying to write it; it shows a lack of effort (to me). I think that people who commit to a topic (5 people must commit to it for it to be formed) should be required to contribute something to the documentation.

Comment: In my view, zero documentation is about people that just through it was cool to have documentation about that tag, not that they are particularly interested in writing them. When I commit to a tag, I should fulfill that commitment.

Comment: Also, the **string** tag is just the same. It should be just closed and forgotten. I don't know what the 5 folks supporting the proposal thought why string will be of any use...

Comment: It might indicate that, like me, someone tried to write documentation on the topic and got so many unhelpful comments from robotic copy-editors that they decided to give up.

Comment: @MichaelKay doubtful, since nobody has ever reviewed a single IR/suggested edit over those tags

Comment: @MichaelKay with a sincere, honest and deep bow towards your professional qualities, and all due respect: you stopped exploring something at the first discomfort - and yet you put vast efforts into expressing your resentment. I am **not** anywhere near you regarding the depth of your knowledge, and I will most likely **never ever be** - yet I have to suggest you to reconsider what you experienced with the Docs site. I think somebody like you can shrug off a snide remark by a robot. At the same time, could you please elaborate on what meaningful examples would "Performance" have?

Comment: Perhaps the same as [windbg]. Simply too few people there to approve edits. And, frankly, who needs debugging and who needs performance? Everyone knows how that works. We need more PHP documentation, because php.net doesn't do it right. We need C# documentation, because MSDN is crappy. We need Java documentation, because it's from Oracle.

Comment: @ThomasWeller what real world examples would be in those two tags? Please explain? These two - performance and debugging - are basic concepts, that can not be documented through examples to not be overly specific. C#, Java and the "overly documented" rest can - but IMHO are not. And when even documented, it is tough to get to the point. This is what Docs is about. **Not a(nother) book.**

Comment: @ppeterka: Not another book? [Using a C# extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/20/extension-methods/33/using-an-extension-method) is a 5298 byte example. It prints on 5 pages when I paste it into Word. Why document C#? C# is already overly specific today. People would rather understand concepts instead of languages. C# and Java are roughly exchangeable. Why document two times?

Comment: @ThomasWeller You are in a misconception about Docs. And **that is a wrong example needing a huge reformat** (and not the only one at that). Docs is **not** an educational site, and was never intended as one. IMHO it is sort of a cheatsheet for professionals who know the concepts, know what they want, but don't want to bother 1000+ pages of useless babble to find out how to use a certain type of encryption, etc. Yep, there are API docs, full of valuable stuff showing a verbal "contract" for the methods, but at least in Java - many constitute a lot of characters and not a lot of content.

Comment: @ppeterka: well, then I'm in misconception. That's totally ok. And I needn't like Docs.

Comment: @ppeterka I do not see why you insist on attacking everyone who has a negative opinion about SOD - especially Thomas's example as that did pertain to this discussion about tags without topics. Since you have started  this though: the main problem still is that SOD is not defined ("It will be defined by us creating it") except in a generic way regarding "examples" which gives no real guidance, has been discussed to death, and is still wrong in a number of peoples opinions. Mine included and yes I have been actively trying to improve it and no I have no hope left for it.

Comment: @ppeterka "you stopped exploring something at the first discomfort" - yes, it made me aware that the site designers had a very different vision from mine about how documentation should work, and therefore it wasn't worth participating.

Comment: @JGreenwell if it looked like attack then I'm sorry (to all parties involved) - was not intended to be one. In my opinion Docs is (sadly) not a good fit for anything but almost-code-only examples. Incidentally, that is something I'd welcome: I can imagine an ideal state of Docs where the recurring questions about the libs, languages, etc we use would have a more efficiently usable "cheatsheet" as opposed to the cryptic and in many cases sloppy official doc. And yes, **we** define what Docs is - including me too. (Also, seems I need a Docs tag with examples on being more subtle in English...)

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for taking time to get back to me. I feel sad that it turned out this way for you - and still do actively encourage you to contribute. If not by writing examples, please at least consider being a moderatory power by reviewing edits and new topics - even if the format is not the one you would wholeheartedly support, the content still could be of the same quality.

Comment: Performance of what?

Comment: @Laurel - doing the right questions since '16